# JQuery Validator Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I've been trying to fix this bug for over an hour and yet - absolutely no luck. I might be missing something simple or it's just me not being aware of something else. Anyway, here's the thing:

I'm trying to add a validation method to my validator which seem to cause troubles. Here's my code:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("isGroupExist", function() {
        var result_value = true;
        $.post('/includes/script_files/isGroupExist.php',   {   authorized: true, 
                                                                groupName: $('#groupName').val() }, function(returnedData) {
            alert(returnedData);
            if(returnedData=='true')
                result_value = false;
            else
                result_value = true;

        });
        return result_value;
    }, "Group Name already exists, please pick a different one."
    );
```

Please pay no attention to how I wrote this, I just tried several approaches to solve the issue. Anyway, the problem is that 'result_value' will never be returned as 'false', even when the variable assigned to it is equal to 'false'. It stays the 'true' for ever, when it is clearly not supposed to. I double checked my function and everything works fine, including the external file. 'returnedData' sometimes comes back as 'true' and sometimes as 'false', but despite its value, 'result_value' won't get updated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like returnedData is a boolean value and you shouldn't be checking its equality to a string.

Comment: returnedData is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I have managed to solve this issue by myself, took a lot of research effort though.

```
$.validator.addMethod("isGroupExist",function(value,element){
        var result =    $.ajax({
                            url: "/includes/script_files/isGroupExist.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            async: false,
                            //data: "action=checkusername&username="+username,
                            data: "authorized=true&groupName="+value,
        }).responseText;
        return result==="good"?false:true;
    },"Group Name already exists, please pick a different one.");
```